# Could humanity buy more time with climate change by blocking out some direct rays of the Sun with an artificial (partial) eclipse?

Tags: sun, climate-science, eclipse

Imagine the Earth faced the imminent crisis from climate change as the planet warmed by 1.5C. As a last ditch attempt to buy more time, humanity finally decided to do whatever it takes to stop the ongoing crisis. In order to cool the planet temporarily, it was decided to block the most direct rays of the Sun for the shortest possible period to have an appreciable impact. What would be involved in such a calculation? There seems to be so many factors: The optimal position of a spacecraft to place a (reflecting) material between the Earth and the Sun. The temperatures that can be withstood by the material. The size of the material. The amount of surface area of the Earth that would need to be blocked from the Sun. The ability of a spacecraft to keep the material positioned between the Earth and the Sun during the Earth's orbit. The duration of time that the Sun would need to be blocked in order for the Earth to radiate more heat than it absorbs - and have a meaningful impact. It seems like this open question would require a huge optimization calculation in order for desperate humans to determine its feasibility. So many factors make it difficult to even begin optimizing this artificial (partial) eclipse...

Comment: The easiest way would be to put many small reflectors in the upper atmosphere. This has happened naturally in the past - google "the year without a summer".

Comment: Thank you Peter.

Answer (score 1):

This is *possible*, but it's going to be so mind-bogglingly expensive you might as well fight climate change directly. Here are some back-of-the-envelope calculations for why it is so expensive to fight climate change this way.

1. The Earth's radius is $6400 km$. To block the Sun's light from the Earth, therefore, you need $\pi * 6400^2 km^2$ of surface area. That's $41$ million $km^2$. The total land surface area of the USA is $9,826,675 km^2$, so you need something the size of 4 USAs.
2. And then you have to send it to space. Getting to space is an extremely expensive affair. The Hubble Space Telescope cost about $2 billion, and its mass is 12,000 kg. Since the hypothetical Earth-shield needs to be so big, it's likely to weigh several million times more than 12,000 kg, so to send it into space would likely cost several million billion dollars. World GDP is about USD 93.86 trillion, so you need several Earths all working on it to afford it.

In practice what you'd do would not be to send up an artificial eclipse, but to modify the atmosphere in some way, e.g. by releasing aerosols (volcanic emissions cool the planet in the same way). This comes with its own set of dangers, as you can undoubtedly see. We got to where we are because we were releasing greenhouse gases into the atmosphere; releasing aerosols could easily have an unintended side-effect. Which is not to say [people aren't looking at it](https://scied.ucar.edu/learning-zone/climate-solutions/limit-sunlight-stop-climate-change) - only that it is not a magic solution to climate change.

Comment: Hi Allure. I take your point, but in fairness, I did not assume that the entire Earth would need to be blocked from the Sun. Only an optimized portion to block direct rays (such as for some Earth surface area close to the equator, etc) such that there could be an impact over several days. Maybe a reflecting material closer to the sun could block more direct rays than if it were closer to the Earth or Moon).

Comment: @RichK I'm not an atmospheric science expert, but that would heat up the world unevenly, likely causing other side-effects. Positioning the reflecting material closer to the Sun would reduce the space required, but it would also require the reflecting material to have some kind of propulsion attached, since objects that are closer to the Sun rotate around the Sun faster, and we need this material to have the same rotational velocity as the Earth. So yeah, it's not a feasible idea.